# Limit of Cox process with lower bounded intensity

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $N(t)$ be a doubly stochastic Poisson process with stochastic intensity $\lambda(t)$. Moreover, let us assume that the intensity is lower bounded by $\bar{\lambda}>0:$
$$\lambda(t)>\bar{\lambda}$$ for all $t>0.$

How can I prove that the process tends to infinity almost surely:
$$N(t)\rightarrow \infty \quad a.s.$$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ ?

This result is well-known for a Poisson process with constant intensity but I can't find a similar result for stochastic intensity. Let us remark that I made the assumption of a strictly positive lower bound to avoid the situation of a Poisson process with vanishing intensity.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In P. Brémaud's book, *Point Process Calculus in Time and Space*, Springer Natural Switzerland AG 2020, Th5.1.16, p.171, there is following theorem:

**Theorem** 5.1.16 Let $N$ be  a simple locally finite point process on $\mathbb{R}_+ $
with the $\mathscr{F}_t $-intensity $\{\lambda(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$. Then
\begin{equation*}
 N(\infty)<\infty \iff \int_0^\infty \lambda(s)\,\mathrm{d}s<\infty, \quad P-a.s.
\end{equation*}
This result is sufficient for your require.

Comment: Thanks, this result perfectly answers my question !